# Help with voltage doubler in a WPT application

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice, low-power, wireless-charging, voltage-doubler

I need some help with this schematic to have higher voltage at Vrect. This is for charging a receiver at 25 mm in a WPT application. I was expecting a voltage of 2Vin at the output of the voltage doubler, but as shown in the simulation, is not working. I'm using inductive coupling to transmit energy [image]  Something wrong is happening and I don't know what[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Care to elaborate on what you think is wrong and what you excepted?

Comment: What is wrong is that the output at Vrect_A doesn't double de voltage for VoutAC_p

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what does it do without I1 in circuit?

Comment: Why not increase the secondary? Voltage doublers are not that effective, and they usually have the same capacitor, over and over (you have a `15n` and `5u`, formed by `C1` and `C2` in series). Not lastly, have you considered that 0.55 A is too much for the doubler? (don't forget to add the `load` flag to the current source, otherwise it will sink current even when the voltage goes negative)

Comment: The 15nF is for the compensation circuit. It's not posible remove it or change it. Also, the 0.55A current source simulates the charge.

Answer (score 1):

The coupling between the two coils is very small. 0.089939 means about only ~9% of the flux from the primary coil is making it to the secondary. Try starting with a K = 1 for an ideal transformer to get things working.

Comment: The thing is that the coils are already designed for that coupling factor. I don't have a transformer, I have PCB coils simulated with Ansys, trying to build optimum coils in a limited area